# Jena won't connect to custom online file

Tags: jena, apache-jena, jena-rules

I tried to connect Jena to my custom file which I stored on a public directory on Dropbox with the following link https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3gfidqqfwvo4e9/foaf.ttl?dl=1.

I've intentionally changed the link to `dl=1` instead of `dl=0` so the link would show directly to the file instead of the Dropbox folder.

In Netbeans I have the following code:

```
    final String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3gfidqqfwvo4e9/foaf.ttl?dl=1";
    final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(url,"TURTLE");
    model.write(System.out);
```

And on the output the only thing I get is:

```
    <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    </rdf:RDF>
```

Any help on why I can't get the entire model?

Comment: This works in the current development branch of Apache Jena even if it does not work in v 3.1.1. It does give 4 HTTP warnings (Invalid cookie header) - maybe in 3.1.1. these cause a silent internal error.  A workaround would be to read the URL into a string and parse the string.

Comment: Though I don't quite understand how I managed to fix the problem by changing the `model.read` function adding an additional blank parameter, now looking as the following: `model.read(url,"","TURTLE")`. As it states in the documentation the second parameter is a baseURI, but I can't understand what does it change when leaving it blank. Nevertheless the code now works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was the Dropbox. Their servers had a problem during the day of my testing and now the code works perfectly.